# main() function at the end of a graphics python returning syntax

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I just redownloaded the graphics.py file, and it's in the same folder as my Python 3.7 folder. I'm trying to learn the graphics interface by typing this simple code in and testing it, however, it keeps giving me an error.

```
    >>> import graphics
    >>> def main():

   win=GraphWin("My Circle", 100,100)

    c=Circle(Point(50,50), 10)

    c.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()

    win.close()

main()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) In this particular case, please make sure your code is properly formatted (paying special attention to indentation for Python code), and post the entire error message.

Comment: if your actual code is formatted as above, it will not work.  Python is doing code blocks with indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Besides proper indentation, if you're going to invoke the classes of Zelle graphics this way, you're going to need a wildcard import:

```
from graphics import *

def main():

    win = GraphWin("My Circle", 100, 100)

    c = Circle(Point(50, 50), 10)

    c.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()

    win.close()

main()
```